# JQuery "long >"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How to query child containers, and not inside containers (thats not about attributes)

```
<div class="container">
   <div>
      <div class="container" child>
           <div>
              <div class="container" inside>
   <div>
      <div class="container" child>
           <div>
              <div class="container" inside>
</div>
```

Edit:
Maybe I can use, something like not()?

.container not(.container)?

Comment: You are aware that you are not closing all those divs like you should? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be missing the point, but I think something in the lines of:

```
$(".container .container:not(.container .container .container)")
```

I.e., all elements who is a "container inside a container" but not those that are a "container in a container in a container".

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div.container > div").find("div.container:first");
```

Comment: By the div, I mean that I dont know = what can be there

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have something to anchor the class selection to a particular div.  I suggest giving the outer one a name.  Then you can find the outer one by name and it's children using the `children` method with the class filter.

```
$('#outerDiv').children('.container');
```